# Is it possible to track all outgoing WCF call?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, reflection

Our application calls external services like

```
//in client factory
FooServiceClient client = new FooServiceClient(binding, endpointAddress);

//in application code
client.BarMethod(); //or other methods
```

Is it possible to track all of these calls (e.g by events or something like that) so that the application can collect the statistics like number of call, response time, etc? Note that my application itself needs to access the values, not only to write to a log file.

What I can think is to create a subclass of VisualStudio-generated FooServiceClient and then add codes like this

```
override void BarMethod()
{
    RaiseStart("BarMethod");
    base.BarMethod();
    RaiseEnd("BarMethod);
}
```

and the RaiseStart and RaiseEnd method will raise events that will be listened by my code.

But this seems tedious (because there are a lot of methods to override) and there is a lot of repeated codes, my code needs to change everytime the service contract changes, etc. Is there a simpler way to achieve this, for example by using reflection to create the subclass or by tapping into a built-in method in WCF, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple way to do it by using dynamic proxy, for example [Castle's Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/).

Firstly, use a factory method to generate your client object

```
IFooClient GetClient()
{        
    FooClient client = new FooClient(); //or new FooClient(binding, endpointAddress); if you want
    ProxyGenerator pg = new ProxyGenerator();
    return pg.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<IFoo>(client, new WcfCallInterceptor());
}
```

And define the interceptor

```
internal class WcfCallInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            RaiseStart(invocation.Method.Name);
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        finally
        {
            RaiseEnd(invocation.Method.Name);
        }
    }

    //you can define your implementation for RaiseStart and RaiseEnd

 }
```

I can also change the intercept method as I wish, for example I can add a catch block to call a different handler in case the method throw exception, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would look at is to see if the counters available in your server's Performance Monitor can provide you with the kind of feedback you need. There's built in counters for a variety of metrics for ServiceModel Endpoints, Operations and Services. Here is some more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could try building an implementation of [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx), which has a method to be called before the request is sent and when the reply is received. You can inspect the message, make logs etc in these methods.

You provide an implementation of [IEndpointBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.aspx) which applies your message inspector, and then add the endpoint behavior to your proxy client instance.

```
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyEndpointBehavior())
```

Check out the docs for MessageInspectors and EndpointBehaviors, there are many different ways of applying them (attributes, code, endpoint xml config), I can't remember of the top of my head which apply to which, as there also IServiceBehavior and IContractBehavior. I do know for sure that the endpoint behaviors can be added to the client proxy collection though.

Comment: cool.. But it seems that with IClientMessageInspector we can't get anything if the message timed out, e.g. due to inaccessible server. Do you know how to also watch when such error happens?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, if there are any errors on the server when invoking the operation a reply will be received by the client, and you can catch them in IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply because the message will have IsFault property of true. I am not sure if you would still get a faulted reply if the client could not access the server.